# Windows Remote Desktop Client fails to connect with error code 0x4 on only one of my computers

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11, remote

I encountered this error message while attempting to connect to a remote host on one of my PCs. I have two computers on the same LAN, and I can easily connect to the remote host using the Windows Remote Desktop client without any issues on my other PC. So this means the remote host is configured correctly.

All settings are identical with no firewall present. What might be causing this issue?

```
[Window Title]
Remote Desktop Connection

[Content]
An internal error has occurred.

[^] Hide details  [OK]

[Expanded Information]
Error code: 0x4
Extended error code: 0x0
Timestamp (UTC): 03/15/24 09:14:35 PM
```

Comment: Are you able to restart the computer with the error?

Comment: Try in the target computer to disable Network Level Authentication (NLA) by setting to `0` the item `UserAuthentication` which may be found in the registry under key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp`, then reboot it.

Comment: @harrymc I tried, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your connection is set to private and not public, I had the same error on a computer that failed to connect when set to public.

Also are the RDP clients on the same version?